# How do I create a knob like on my amplifier

Tags: potentiometer

On my amp, I have a big round knob, that I can turn forever in both directions, to control volume. 
It simply turns up whenever I turn clockwise and down when I turn counter clockwise. There is no limit as to how far I can keep turning it.

How do I create this in my own project?
I have an arduino where I want a knob like this, to control a value in the arduino memory. Simply, turning up, add to value, turning down, subtract from value.

I assume I need some kind of potentiometer, but they do not turn forever, do they?

Comment: Actually there are potentiometers, usually with two wipers, that do turn forever.  However, those are not approriate for what you are asking about.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you need in a rotary encoder, they have two outputs that generate pulses which are then decoded to read the direction of rotation.

[image: Rotary mechanical encoder]  [image: Rotary mechanical encoder waveform]

Refer to http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/RotaryEncoders

To control the volume you can use Arduino to drive a volume control chip like [PGA2311](http://www.ti.com/litv/sbos218a).
There are even 4 channel versions like [PGA4311](http://www.ti.com/litv/sbos230a)

You can also control digital potentiometers like [MCP41xxx/42xxx](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/11195c.pdf)

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento `I suggest not to link Arduino directly with the answer` The OP asked specifically for Arduino so why including an Arduino link with a library for his needs is wrong?

Comment: ops, have not read that, sorry :)